# C# httpclient get response

Tags: c#, php, server, httpclient

I used httpClient to send data to the server. I can check the response successfully, but my response string is in a php file. I don't know how to access this string in php with something like:

```
if user exist echo true; 
else echo false;
```

I tried with WebClient class. It worked but I was unable to check if it's response is successful.

Here is the code:

```
public Boolean authorization(String korisnik, String zaporka)
{
     var client = new HttpClient();

     var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
     {
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("korisnik", korisnik),
         new KeyValuePair<string, string>("zaporka", zaporka)
     };

     var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);

     var response = client.PostAsync("http://www.etfos.unios.hr/~tsapina/autorizacija.php", content).Result;
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response);
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
          MessageBox.Show("success respond");
          return false;
      }
     return true;
}
```

I need to get result in a php file output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check the `Content` has value, then `ReadAsStringAsync()` for the content. It's JSON though, so you'll need to parse it.

Here, I use `JsonConvert.Serialize<Dictionary<string,string>>()` from **[Json .NET](http://ewtonsoft.net/)** to deserialize the JSON to a `Dictionary<string, string>` object, which you can use to access the data. May I also suggest using `async` and `await` to make use of asynchronous functions properly:

```
public async bool Authorization(string korisnik, string zaporka){
    ...
    try {
        //will always throw an exception if not successful
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.etfos.unios.hr/~tsapina/autorizacija.php", content);

        if (httpResponse.Content != null) {
            var responseContent = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(responseContent);

            Console.WriteLine(dict["post_var_key"]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Error occured: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @markomarinovic See the update for `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`. That will make sure it throws an exception if there's any error returned too.